# How to assign one array value to another array in php

Tags: php, arrays

For Example :

```
$variable = Array(
[0] => Array( [id]=>"1" [file]=>"new" )
[1] => Array( [id]=>"2" [file]=>"sample" )
[2] => Array( [id]=>"3" [file]=>"hello" )
[3] => Array( [id]=>"4" [file]=>"garden" )
[4] => Array( [id]=>"5" [file]=>"door" )
[5] => Array( [id]=>"6" [file]=>"tem" )
)
```

**How to assign All *file* row into to one Array Value Like**

```
$test =$variable["file"]
print_r($test);
```

Output:

```
Array( 
[0] => "new" 
[1] => "sample 
[2] => "hello" 
[3] => "garden" 
[4] => "door" 
[5] => "tem"
)
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not show an attempt to write code or solve the problem themselves.

Comment: @JohnConde - you're being generous with use of the word "question", i dont see a question anywhere.

Comment: Taking a look into the array section of the manual wouldn't be too much to ask for neither. http://php.net/array_column

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using PHP 5.5 you can use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
 $new_array = array_column($array, 'file');
```

Comment: Cool.  This function is long overdue in PHP!

Answer (score 2):

I do this all the time actually:

```
$test = array();
foreach($variable as $v){
  $test[] = $v['file'];
}
print_r($test);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array_map(function($item) {return $item['file'];}, $variable);
print_r($result);
```